# How to edit parts of a line in a text file in java

Tags: java, file, line

I'm trying to delete the last four characters of all the lines in a text file. Let's say I have domain.txt and the content:

```
123.com 

student.com

tech.net
```

running into hundreds of lines. How do I delete the last four characters (the extensions) to remain:

```
123

student

tech
```

etc.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Any chances of lines containing extensions like `'.co.uk'`, `'.gov.xyz'`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

**UPDATED**

```
    String a ="123.com";
    System.out.println(a.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf(".")));
```

Comment: i dont know much of java, can you write the whole code. dont forget it runs in hundreds of line. the program should be able to run through the file and produce a new edited file

Comment: I'm willing to help not to do other people's work. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below :

```
   File file = new File("file.txt");
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
   String line = "", 
   newtext = "";
   while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      line=line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf("."))

      newtext += line + "\n";
  }
  reader.close();

 // Now write new Content

  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.txt");
  writer.write(newtext);
  writer.close();
```

Do not forget to use try..catch

Comment: where do i write the main code? pardon my knowledge of java

Comment: in your main function or any other function